# Match pyspark dataframe column to list and create a new column

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have the below list.

```
lst=['name','age','country']
```

I have the below `pyspark` `dataframe`

```
column_a   column_b
Aaaa       name,age,subject
Bbbb       name,age,country,subject
Cccc       name,subject,percentage
```

I have to compare the list with `column_b` and check if the values in the list are part of the column and create a new column and populate it with the values from the list that are available in `column_b`.

Below is the expected output.

```
column_a column_b                 column_c              
Aaaa     name,age,subject         name,age
Bbbb     name,age,country,subject name,age,country
Cccc     name,subject,percentage  name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Without Duplicates

[`array_intersect`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_intersect.html) allows for the operation you want to achieve.

> `array_intersect` does not allow for duplicates, (i.e, ) if `column_b` had a value of `["name", "name"]` then  `column_c` would contain `["name"]` once.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [("Aaaa", ["name", "age", "subject"],),
        ("Bbbb", ["name", "age", "country", "subject"],),
        ("Cccc", ["name", "subject", "percentage"],),
        ("Dddd", ["name", "name"],),]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("column_a", "column_b",))

lst=['name','age','country']
lit_lst = [F.lit(v) for v in lst]

df.withColumn("column_c", F.array_intersect(F.col("column_b"), F.array(lit_lst))).show(truncate=False)
```

#### Output

```
+--------+-----------------------------+--------------------+
|column_a|column_b                     |column_c            |
+--------+-----------------------------+--------------------+
|Aaaa    |[name, age, subject]         |[name, age]         |
|Bbbb    |[name, age, country, subject]|[name, age, country]|
|Cccc    |[name, subject, percentage]  |[name]              |
|Dddd    |[name, name]                 |[name]              |
+--------+-----------------------------+--------------------+
```

### Preserve Duplicates

To preserve duplicates, [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#filter) Higher Order Function can be applied.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [("Aaaa", ["name", "age", "subject"],),
        ("Bbbb", ["name", "age", "country", "subject"],),
        ("Cccc", ["name", "subject", "percentage"],),
        ("Dddd", ["name", "name"],),]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("column_a", "column_b",))

df.withColumn("column_c", F.array(lit_lst))\
  .withColumn("column_c", F.expr("filter(column_b, element -> array_contains(column_c, element))"))\
  .show(truncate=False)
```

#### Output

```
+--------+-----------------------------+--------------------+
|column_a|column_b                     |column_c            |
+--------+-----------------------------+--------------------+
|Aaaa    |[name, age, subject]         |[name, age]         |
|Bbbb    |[name, age, country, subject]|[name, age, country]|
|Cccc    |[name, subject, percentage]  |[name]              |
|Dddd    |[name, name]                 |[name, name]        |
+--------+-----------------------------+--------------------+
```